# Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError in the except clause of my Python script?

Tags: python, exception

I have the following part of code from a Python script.

```
status = 'success'
try:
 sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except Exception as e:
  #traceback.print_exc()
  error_message = e
#  print str(e)
  status = 'fail'
print ("{},{},{},{}".format(hivedb,table,status,error_message)) 
sys.exit(1)
```

Here in this part of code, if there is an `exception` then I am setting `error_message`.

If there is no error, then I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment`.

What I want is if there is no error, I want the `error_message` set to `No error`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Under `status = 'success'`, put `e = 'No error'`. Then it is defined before the try/except. I'm not sure why you want this kind of setup, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach for this is to use an `else`, since state updates should be atomic.

```
try:
    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except Exception as e:
    status = 'fail'
    error_message = e
else:  # Executes only if no Exception.
    status = 'success'
    error_message = 'No error'
```

As a side note, it's a bad idea to do blanket exception-catching with `except Exception`. You should specify the type of exception you're getting or you risk catching others, like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `error_message` before the try/catch block as you have already for `status`:

```
status = 'success'
error_message = 'No error'
try:
    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except Exception as e:
    error_message = e
    status = 'fail'
```

Comment: Note that since there is no scope associated with a `try` statement, you can also simply set `e = 'No error'`, and do away with `error_message`; `e` is still bound to the caught exception after the `try` statement completes. (In Python 2, anyway; in Python 3, `e` is in fact only in scope for the body of the `except` clause.)

Comment: @MrJLP I have got the desired result but the overall script is giving me wrong results.

Comment: @mtjlp Please have a look at the added code that come after my initial code in the script